# 2d array is not being filled as expected

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to make a gamebord created out of a self made object Square in a 2d array.
When i create it in my constructor, only the first array is created and the second array is full of Null.
When i try this with Int, it does work correctly.
Do i need to add something special to my Square class to make it possible to make 2d arrays of or am i missing something else?

```
public class Bord {

private Square[][] gameBord;

public Bord(int hoogte, int breedte) {
        if (isGameBordSizeValid(hoogte, breedte)) {
            gameBord = new Square[breedte][hoogte];
            //populateMiddleOfBord(hoogte, breedte);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("GameBord size is not valid");
        }

    }
```

[image: V]

My Square class

```
public class Square {

    private final Integer lengte;
    private final Integer breedte;
    private boolean isBezet;
    private Stone steen;

    public Square() {
        this.lengte = 4;
        this.breedte = 4;
        this.isBezet = false;
    }

    public void squareWordBezet(Color kleur) {
        if (!getIsBezet()) {
            isBezet = true;
            this.steen = new Stone(kleur);
        }

    }

    public boolean getIsBezet() {
        return isBezet;
    }

}
```

Comment: Java is not really my area of expertise, but I assume that it works with integers because they are primitive (i.e. value) types wheres your classes are reference types. This would make the code above effectively create an array of uninitialized references, the solution to which being to iterate over all entries and assign an new instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize each of the elements of the array. Like this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < breedte;i++){
   for(int k = 0;k < lengte;k++){
       gameBord[i][k] = new Rect(//parameters here");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to populate your array with Square objects too.  Right now, all you have is the array, not the objects it should contain.